# How to set Socket.io (v1.7.3) connection globally in the WebPack + ReactJS project?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, socket.io

I have to pass the socket as props to my React-components:

```
<Component1 socket={this.state.socket}/>
```

Accordingly, to subscribe to messages from the server in another component, or in the child component, I need to transfer it again to their properties.
It's horrible.
So... 
How to set Socket.io (v1.7.3) connection globally in the WebPack + ReactJS project?
To use socket.on() and socket.emit() without declaration in each component.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention, I guess that you're not using [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/)?
From its homepage:

> Flux is the application architecture that Facebook uses for building client-side web applications. It complements React's composable view components by utilizing a unidirectional data flow. It's more of a pattern rather than a formal framework, and you can start using Flux immediately without a lot of new code.

If you use Flux, you won't have to pass the socket object around while can still perform communications between it and React components very well.
For example, with the following format:

```
const Dispatcher = require('./Dispatcher)';
const socket = require('socket.io-client')();

// Listen to events from server -> Emit them to listeners in the client app
socket.on('EVENT_A', data => {
  data.type = 'EVENT_A';
  Dispatcher.dispatch(data);
});

// Listen to events from the client app -> Emit them to server
Dispatcher.register(payload => {
  switch(payload.type) {
    case 'EVENT_B':
      socket.emit('EVENT_B', payload.data);
      break;
    case 'EVENT_QUIT':
      socket.disconnet();
      location.assign('/exit');
      break;
    default: break;
  }
});
```

You can put socket-related code inside a single file, and Flux's dispatcher will do all the communication works, either through Flux stores or to the React components themselves directly.

Comment: Can i use socket like old-style coding?
For example:
We connected the script:
var socket = io ('/');

And then, used it wherever necessary.

Comment: alternatively, I believe that you can export the socket object after initializing it, then other modules can reference it through `var socket = require('path-to-socket')`